# Accessing Azure Vision API from R Studio

Tags: r, azure, azure-cognitive-services, vision

https://portal.vision.cognitive.azure.com/demo/extract-text-from-images

I would like to access this API within R studio and get the same output.

Currenlty AzureVision::read_text() is close, but not the same output. Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers!

I have tried this, but it is not working:

```
api_endpoint_url <- 'https://XXXXXXX.cognitiveservices.azure.com/vision/v3.2/read/analyze'
api_key <- 'XXXXX'

image_url = 'C:/XXX/image.jpg'
reqURL = paste(api_endpoint_url)

APIresponse = POST(url = reqURL,
content_type('application/json'),add_headers(.headers = c('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' = api_key)),body=list(url = image_url),encode = "json")
```

Answer (score 0):

- According to this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts-sdk/client-library?tabs=visual-studio&pivots=programming-language-rest-api) there are only 5 ways to connect to OCR 3 of them are through languages such c#, JavaScript and python and the other 2 are through REST Api and vision studio.
- Also , as far as I know you need to pass the authentication bearer token with post request. To get the bearer token you need azure ad app registration refer this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/get-azure-active-directory-token)
- So you can ether again use R to make the rest api or you can run a python script in R studio
- To run Python first you need `reticulate` package installed

```
install.packages('reticulate')
```

then we load the library using

```
library(reticulate)
```

Now we can run python script using the following command.

```
py_run_file("<Path to your script>")
```

- If your script needs any packages, you can install them using

```
py_install('<Package Name>')
```